# how to export a Json file with phpAdmin without COMMENTS (// ..... */)

Tags: php, json

I have a .json file exported with phpAdmin tool. My problem is that json is invalid.... I ask me how is possible that Phpadmin exports a Json file that is not correct? Comments in my file are the biggest problem. Please help me because when I attach this .json they tell me that this json is Invalid. And Firebase can't use this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't ignore the comment generation in JSON format, if you have access to the phpMyAdmin source code on your server you can remove the comment generation yourself pretty easily in the file

> phpMyAdmin/libraries/plugins/export/ExportJson.php

see the `exportHeader` function and for the other comments just search the file for `//` (it's not that long).

If you don't have access to the phpMyAdmin source code you may be able to remove the comments after the file creation (either manually or with a program on your computer if you just need it once or a few times). You can use two regular expressions for that, if you need further help I can post an example.

Comment: Thanks for help. My .json file is huge and I can't remove comments manually. Can you show me your regular expressions? I'm searching with my friend if we have access to the phpAdmin source code. I'll tell you soon

Comment: @PancrazioSchito it depends how you want to remove the comments, if it's only 1 large file you can use a simple text editor, most of them provide a text replace with reg ex search. e.g. Notepad++, Sublime or even eclipse IDE.

Comment: i have only 2 .json file . But my plantbook.json is very huge. the file have 43000 lines of code and Notepad++ and Sublime open it very slowly and I have problem to edit them manually despite my pc is an i7 etc... i need one correct .json file to upload in firebase and use it in my android application.

Comment: Well, even if it takes a little to open the files (43000 lines shoud not be that much as long as the file is below 100 MB). Anyway as far as I know there is only one header comment with `/** ... */` so you can remove that by hand and the other comments are just simple line comments e.g. `// comment goes here`, so you can remove them with a search & replace in Notepad++. use this reg ex search `^//.*`, make sure to check the regular expression option in the search dialog and ". matches newline" sould be unchecked. Then replace all (you can try find next to test the search first).